# Chrome extension refusing to load script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am getting an error for my chrome extension which I don't know the cause of.

> "Refused to load the script
> 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@supabase/supabase-js@1.9.1' because it
> violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
> 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so
> 'script-src' is used as a fallback. "
>
> and "Refused to load the script
> 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@supabase/supabase-js@1.9.1' because it
> violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
> 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules'
> http://localhost:* [http://127.0.0.1:*"](http://127.0.0.1:*%22). Note that 'script-src-elem'
> was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback. "

this is my manifest.json file:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "My extension",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "identity"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "app.js"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_title": "My extension",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "/icons/16.png",
            "48": "/icons/48.png",
            "128": "/icons/128.png"
        }
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "css": [],
            "js": ["popup.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://*.supabase.co/*"
    ]
}
```

I have tried many things but I cannot find the documentation for what I am trying to do. I do not know which permissions are needed. I can barely even find a guide out there of doing authentication on a manifest v3 chrome extension.

Comment: Did you migrate from V2 to V3?

Comment: ManifestV3 doesn't allow external scripts by design. Put the file into your extension and load it like you load your own scripts.

Comment: @wOxxOm How do I do that? I need supabase-js in my extension.

Comment: Well you either literally put the file into your extension (after downloading it) or use webpack to compile a bundle.

Comment: Please tell me which one of the folders I need to add. Or do I need to add the entire repository? https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js